# Javascript: Use reduce() method to find the LCM in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the LCM(least common multiples) among several numbers in an array. To get a LCM between each two numbers in the array, I use the `reduce()` method which is not working.Please tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

```
function gcd(a,b){
  //gcd: greatest common divisor
  //use euclidean algorithm
  var temp = 0;
  while(a !== 0){
    temp = a;
    a = b % a;
    b = temp; 
  }
  return b;
}

function lcm(a,b){
  //least common multiple between two numbers
  return (a * b / gcd(a,b));
}

function smallestCommons(arr) {
  //this function is not working, why?
  arr.reduce(function(a, b){
    return lcm(a, b);
  });

}

smallestCommons([1,2,3,4,5]);
//------>undefined
```

Comment: Take debugger and debug your code.

Comment: You just forgot to `return` from `smallestCommons`. The `reduce` is working.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, I first thought `return lcm(a, b);` will return me the result.

Comment: @ZacharyWang: That does `return` from the callback function that you're passing to `reduce`, it does not `return` from the `smallestCommons` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `smallestCommons` function is missing a `return`. `undefined` is the default return value for all functions that don't have an explicit `return`.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(lcm);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I first thought return lcm(a, b); will return me the result.